# Why does powershell not recognize cmdlets in a script called by a windows service?

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, service

We have a windows service which runs as the local system account. It calls a PowerShell script and retrieves the output for further processing. It works like a charm under windows server 2016 but now needs to be moved to a windows server 2012 R2. On this machine, it does not recognize the azure specific cmdlets.

I tried to install the specific cmdlets via `-Scope AllUsers`. We also logged into the PowerShell directly as `local system`-user; it does recognize the cmdlets (e.g. `Add-AzureRMAccount`) correctly.

C#:

```
PowerShell psInstance = PowerShell.Create();
psInstance.AddScript(scriptBase + "getVMs.ps1");
var azureVMList = psInstance.Invoke();
```

getVMs.ps1:

```
$finalPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force

$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $accountName, $finalPassword

$trash = Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $tenantID -ServicePrincipal`
```

We don't understand why the cmdlets are working fine under the same circumstances on server 2016 and if we run them directly as the user.

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: What happens if you add `Import-Module AzureRM.Profile` to `getVMs.ps1`?

Comment: What `Azure RM PowerShell` version is installed on your Windows Server 2012? `Add-AzureRmAccount` is e.g. not supported on version `2.5.0`, so you may have to update `Azure RM Powershell` -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.profile/add-azurermaccount?view=azurermps-4.4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-2.5.0

Comment: AzureRM.Profile is installed in Version 5.8.2. Adding that statement to the script does not change anything. As mentioned before, the script itself runs perfectly fine in the PowerShell-Window. Even as the local-system user which runs the service.

It just does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Can you show us the full error from where you deduced that _" it does not recognize the azure specific cmdlets"_ ?

Comment: The original message is in german, so here is the translated one from my log file:

"The term "Add-AzureRmAccount" was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if the path is correct (if included), and try again."

I've got the same message for the command "Get-AzureRmVm"

Comment: Is the module available in one of the PowerShell module paths (` $env:PSModulePath`)?

Comment: Are the `AzureRM` cmdlets even supported prior to Server 2016?

Comment: Yes, it is available.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 as I said, the script runs fine if I run it manually. It also produces the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a workaround here, in your c# code, directly import the module which contains the cmdlet.

1.you can use this command to get the module file(I'm using az module, feel free to change to azureRm module):

```
(Get-Module -Name az.accounts).Path
```

then you can see the module file path, in my side, it's "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Accounts\1.5.2\Az.Accounts".

2.in your c# code:

```
InitialSessionState initial = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
initial.ImportPSModule(new string[] {"the full path of Az.Accounts.psd1, if it does not work, try full path of Az.Accounts.psm1"} );
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
runspace.Open();     
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = runspace;
ps.AddScript(scriptBase + "getVMs.ps1");
var azureVMList = psInstance.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did help. Had to add a couple of modules, but now works like a charm!